# Passing an anonymous namespace map to a function from another file

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to call a function from a different file by passing a local map variable.

```
#include "fileWithfuncA.h"

namespace
{
std::map<std::string, int> someMap = funcThatReturnsCorrectMap();
}

A(someMap);
```

```
// this is the different file with function A
A(const std::map<std::string, int>& inputMap)
{
stuff here
}
```

If I iterate through the items in the inputMap of function A, it shows that the input map is empty.

On the other hand, when I do this.

```
#include "fileWithAfunc.h"

namespace
{
std::map<std::string, int> someMap = funcThatReturnsCorrectMap();
}

A({{"aa",1},{"bb",2}});
```

The inputMap of A has all the correct values. But I don't want to hardcode the input of A and also I can't change the content of function A, so how could I go about passing the correct map (the variable someMap) to A?

edit:
The functThatReturnsCorrectMap looks like the following. The function works because I have tested its output outside of calling function A

```
std::map<std::string, int> functThatReturnsCorrectMap()
{
    std::map<std::string, int>  correctMap;
    for (auto const& [type, name] : someMap)
    {
       int index = 1;
       correctMap.insert({name, index});
    }
    return correctMap;
}
```

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. This problem may be due to a bug in `funcThatReturnsCorrectMap` or an initialization order error. `A` is being called somewhere, and it isn't at the namespace scope, so the code provided is incomplete. Edit : I suspect the anonymous namespace is not related.

Comment: Show your funcThatReturnsCorrectMap function.
Taking into account that you lost the resulting type of A function, you could do something similar with the funcThatReturnsCorrectMap.

Comment: I've included a function that is very similar to functThatReturnsCorrectMap(). The values of returned map is correct, as I have tested it in other places in that file; it only has a problem when it's given as an input to function A.

Comment: In the function `functThatReturnsCorrectMap`, a empty `map` is returned, so  the iteration get nothing.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've fixed that typo, I copied from my actual function and forgot to change that. The return value of functThatReturnsCorrectMap is correct. I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong with scopes.

Comment: Is `A(someMap);` really just at global scope, outside of any function, as you've shown?

Comment: Is `someMap` used in the implementation of `functThatReturnsCorrectMap` the same `someMap` that this very function is supposed to initialize?